# Neat 2.0 - Setting the grid size from full-width to specific px

Tags: html, sass, neat, css-frameworks

I have currently started messing around with the new [Neat 2.0 framework](http://neat.bourbon.io/docs/latest/#). Previously in [1.8](http://neat.bourbon.io/docs/1.8.0/) when creating the grid the `outer-container()` mixin accepted an actual number for the size of your grid. However now with using Sass mapping the `grid-container()` mixin only accepts a sass map with the following attributes.

```
$my-custom-grid: (
  columns: 12,
  gutter: 20px,
  media: 1200px,
  color: rgba(#00d4ff, 0.25),
  direction: ltr,
);
```

From what it appears, this just makes the grid the full screen width by default. How do I make a grid that is only 960px wide but still collapses when you start to shrink the browser size?

I feel like now I'll constantly be shifting elements so that they're not on the edge of the browser. I'm sure there's a way around this but just setting the width of the element where I call `grid-container()` doesn't work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: have you tried using `max-width: 960px;` in the class you're putting `grid-container()` in?

Comment: Haha yes, I did indeed and that solved the problem.  I wasn't certain if that would mess with the grid system but since all the column widths use `calc()` now it hasn't caused any issues. Thank you for replying! @tec4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS `max-width` is the answer! It wont set the width of the container but rather keep the container from going past the given value. That way the `width: calc()` will still work as intended.

Comment: I can confirm that this is indeed the answer! Haha, thank you!

Comment: You can accept this answer so other users can know right away what the answer is. @NathanHulsey